# Download Azure File Share Documents Programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, fileshare, azure-files

I am on a project where the ability to download documents (.pdf's) from an Azure File Storage account would be useful. Is this possible? I am currently only able to output the directories and directory's file content paths as strings, but unable to access the files at those paths, using the Microsoft.Azure namespace.

Additional details: In C#/ASP.NET, being deployed as an Azure Web App

Thank you.

C

Comment: Yes, it is possible to download these files. Are you just looking for a sample code? If that's the case, check this out https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Samples/GettingStarted/VisualStudioQuickStarts/DataFileStorage/Program.cs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Here is a demo for your reference:

My File Share and one picture file as below:

[image]

My code as below:

```
    public static void DownloadFromFileStorage()
    {
        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=leeliublob;AccountKey=OxxxxxxxxQSy2vkvSi/x/e9l9FhLqayXcbxxxxxJ5Wjkly1DsQPYY5dF2JrAVHtBozbJo29ZrrGJA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");
        CloudFileClient client = account.CreateCloudFileClient();


        //get File Share
        CloudFileShare cloudFileShare = client.GetShareReference("myfile");

        //get the related directory
        CloudFileDirectory root = cloudFileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();
        CloudFileDirectory dir = root.GetDirectoryReference("Folder1");

        //get the file reference
        CloudFile file = dir.GetFileReference("1.PNG");

        //download file to local disk
        file.DownloadToFile("C:\\Test\\1.PNG", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

    }
```

Screenshot of result:

[image]

Comment: To have this working do we need to have the File Share called "myfile" pre-setup?

Comment: i get a compile error : 'IListFileItem' does not conain a defenition for 'DownloadToFile' and no extention method 'DownloadToFile' accepting a first argument of type 'IListFileItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) when I try the download to file line , any ideas to why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer  yanivtwin the download to file would be:

file.GetFileReference("1.PNG").DownloadToFile("FolderPath",System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

Answer (score -1):

This is not a .NET solution. I am including this solution for anyone using Windows and would prefer a really simple solution to download any file(s) from a blob.
The easiest way to do this is using the [`azcopy` command.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-files#download-a-directory)
Download the `azcopy`.exe from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#download-azcopy)
For windows - Start cmd and start the downloaded .exe by going to the downloaded folder.

```
cd <folder-with-azcopy.exe>
azopy.exe
```

Then go to your Storage Account -> Under Settings go to Shared Access Signature -> Create and Get the SAS Token.

Run the following in CMD: SAS token starts with `?sig=...`, `<local-directory-path>` is the folder you wish to download everything to (`C:/Users/.../download`).

```
azcopy cp 'https://<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net/<file-share-name>/<directory-path><SAS-token>' '<local-directory-path>' --recursive=True
```

Comment: the OP was asking programmatically

Comment: Microsoft has created an entire library for handling and working with all of the Azure Storage Containers. Also, we aren't 100% sure if OP is looking for a .Net core option, which would make using a .exe hard to do on a Linux server. Also, it can be tough to programmatically get progress from an external executable can become a programmatic nightmare. Also, as stated above, OP was requesting code as a solution.

Comment: Yes Kevin, I agree. I was facing a similar problem and wanted an easy way to download files to my Windows system. I included this in case it helps someone else facing a similar issue and they stumble across this question. But yes, I agree. Point well taken.